# http.TimeoutHandler returns but handlerfunc keeps running

Tags: http, go, server, timeout

I am testing the `http.timeoutHandler` in my go web server, I noticed that after 3 seconds my client call receives a "`Timeout`" message, but 2 seconds later I can see on server logs the message "My `func Println`". Why the `TimeoutHandler` didn't cancel my `func1`?

This is the code I am using:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "net/http"
        "time"
)

func func1(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("My func Println")
        io.WriteString(w, "My func!\n")
}

func main() {
        srv := http.Server{
                Addr:         ":9000",
                WriteTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
                Handler:      http.TimeoutHandler(http.HandlerFunc(func1), 3*time.Second, "Timeout!\n"),
        }

        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Server failed: %s\n", err)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is how it's intended to work.

When the timeout happens and your handler function still runs (haven't returned), the request's context will be cancelled. Your handler is responsible to monitor the Context's Done channel, and abort its work if cancel is requested. Each handler runs in its own goroutine, and goroutines cannot be killed or interrupted from the "outside".

Example how to do it:

```
func func1(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    select {
    case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("My func Println")
        io.WriteString(w, "My func!\n")
    case <-req.Context().Done():
        fmt.Println("Cancelled")
    }
}
```

This wil output:

```
Cancelled
```

If you'd change the delay in the handler to 2 seconds:

```
case <-time.After(2 * time.Second):
```

Output would be:

```
My func Println
```

And client receives the sent data:

```
My func!
```